# Stuck at integrating worldpay using cocoapods

Tags: ios, worldpay

I am integrating worldpay using cocoapods into my project but am getting these errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libWorldpay.a(Worldpay.o)
>         objc-class-ref in libWorldpay.a(ThreeDSController.o)
>         objc-class-ref in libWorldpay.a(APMController.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libWorldpay.a(WorldpayUtils.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Would anyone help me solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: any one help me out from this issue

Answer (score 0):

`_AFHTTPRequestOperation` and `_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` are `AFNetworking` classes. I think you may also need to add the `AFNetworking` pod.

Answer (score 0):

platform :ios, '7.0'
  pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"

Need to add to implement this effectively since worldpay is dependent on AFNetworking

https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-lib-ios